# how to hide sensitive data while logging in C#?

Tags: c#

I am getting static code analysis error as `log injection` for below C# code.

```
public void Get(string studentId)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Getting the details for student {studentId}...");
```

and here is the error,

> This is a security audit finding.
> CID 2481738 (#2 of 2): Log injection (LOG_INJECTION)
> 4. sink: Calling LogInformation. This call uses System.String.Format("Getting the details for student {0}...", studentId) for sensitive computation

It appears that I need to sanitize `studentId` the input.

What's the best way to sanitize it as this is string and we're using in logs entries ?

Is `{WebUtility.HtmlEncode(studentId)}` will work?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: `This is a security audit finding. CID 2481738 (#2 of 2): Log injection (LOG_INJECTION) 4. sink: Calling LogInformation. This call uses System.String.Format("Getting the details for student {0}...", studentId) for sensitive computation`

Comment: Is that actually a security problem though? I mean, you can't trick `String.Format` into doing anything, other than string concatenation. It's what you would do with the string, *after* it has been formatted that might be an issue.

Comment: this is static code analysis error from the tool `Coverity`. Are you saying `C# string interpolation` style of writing is the problem here and if I use `String.Format` , it will solve the problem?

Comment: Imagine if the `studentId` string consists of (assuming ids are meant to be numeric) `123\nSpurious log message claiming something else`. If the log target is a text file meant to contain one log message per line, you now have that extra spurious entry in the log (insert any other fields that may also be required). Only you can decide if that's an issue you need to guard against.

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, let say I need to guard `studentId`, what best I can write in C#

Comment: To me it seems the error message relates to String.Format, not to the LogInformation. Yes, it mentions it, but then spends about 80% of the error message explaining why String.Format is a problem. But, all this hinges on the assumption that passing strange strings to `_logger.LogInformation` is going to be a problem. Is it? I do understand that with the proper encoded string, it could look like in the log that something happened, that didn't, but if the logger class handles it, not so much.

Comment: Though, it is of course correct to highlight the call as problematic. It doesn't automatically mean that something is wrong though, it means extra care needs to be taken to analyze the situation and see what, if anything, is wrong.

Comment: I don't know what "Logger" you are using. but I believe most of the logger should have to have sanitizing important data. Example:
Serlilog has enricher to hide sensitive data - https://github.com/serilog-contrib/Serilog.Enrichers.Sensitive

If your logger doesn't provide such functionality, you make custome one, probably I would start with wring LogHelper class to help creating the log later you can refactor to any extent! Your log helper would provide formatting logs, and also would mask/replace sensitive data and return the log string to your "logger"!

Comment: and I think title should be updated to say : " how to hide sensitive data while logging?"